# C Linked lists implementation

Tags: c, list, linked-list, malloc, implementation

I have problem understanding implementation of linked lists, I get basic idea, but I have one question:

```
new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node))
```

Why do we use here (node*)? Why don't we just say:

```
new_node = malloc(sizeof(node))?
```

Thanks for the answer in advance.

```
typedef struct node{
 int value;
 struct node* next_node;
}node;

node* create_node(int v){
 node* new_node;

 new_node=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
 if(new_node==NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocation problem.\n");
    exit(1);
 }
 new_node->value=v;
 new_node->next_node=NULL;

 return new_node;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, the article also explains why `sizeof(node_type)` is a bad idea, and what should be used instead. In addition, I prefer `!new_node` to `new_node == NULL`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `malloc ()` is a void pointer.

This void pointer is safely promoted to the struct type without any casting.

So you do not need to cast the result of `malloc()`.

But it is a good coding practice to include the cast. 
You can read the detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). 
Corrections: @UnderDog

Comment: NO! N0!, and NO!
There is absolutely no need to cast.

Comment: @UnderDog Can you correct me plz.

Comment: You do not need to cast the result of malloc in C.

Comment: I just looked this answer, is it correct now?

Comment: Yes the answer is correct. Read the already existing question for details.